# XCode ios build places blue tint on images

Tags: ios, xcode, core-motion

XCode leaves a blue tint over the images in my iOS application, I have tried looking at the Debug settings, because the Apple Developer site states that CoreMotion places the overlay on the images, however, none of the settings are on in there. I have searched around for a few days before actually posting here, and at this point it is just really annoying. I thought it would be only on my test build, so I archived it and uploaded it to iTunes connect to have someone else try, with the same results, all the images were blue.

Note: This only happens when building on a device, the simulator does not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: did you set a global tintcolor anywhere? does it help if you apply a tintcolor of UIColor.clearColor() to the image?

Comment: No I do not believe so, and I am using SFML, all of the Obj-C code is done in the libraries, there is no way for me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason XCode compressing the image files mangled how the library I am using (SFML) read the file. Turning off PNG compression in settings fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needing this information 6 years later:

I have been using the SFML framework to try to build to multiple platforms (macOS, iOS, & Windows) within the last few days and I had this same issue with the iOS builds.

For each image that has the blue tint I had to manually go in and change the type in the File Inspector from PNG to BMP (or some other image type). Otherwise Xcode would compress the PNG and give it that blue tint.

Comment: Isn't this the same as the existing answer?